# Create Windows Console application in VS 2012

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2012

How can I create a Windows Console application in VS 2012?

Here it is:

[image: descriptionn]

Comment: Please be more specific. What type of console application? What are you trying to do? Also, please add a description for your images.

Comment: Win32 Console Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I create a Windows Console application in VS 2012?

You need to install `**Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop**` instead of `**Visual Studio Express for Windows 8**`.  Marcus Karlsson provided the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758124/how-do-i-create-a-console-application-in-visual-studio-express-for-windows-8) over at Stackoverflow with regards to **Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop**.

> There are different versions of Visual Studio 2012 Express.
>
> Visual Studio Express for Windows 8 is targeted against building
>   software for Windows Store using the new tiled interface. It will not
>   allow you to build console applications.
>
> The version which you should use is called Visual Studio Express for
>   Windows Desktop, it covers more traditional Windows development
>   including console applications.
>
> Once you have installed Express for Windows Desktop launch it and
>   create a C++ console application project. You can then select to build
>   your solution from the Build menu, and run it from the Debug menu.

## VisualStudio.com Links:

- [List of available previous versions of Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/)
- [List of available previous versions of Visual Studio 2012](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202012&wt.mc_id=o~msft~vscom~older-downloads)